# Does this Definition of "Subformula" in Propositional Logic Seem Correct?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am reading *A First Course in Logic* by Shawn Hedman. On page three I read:

> **Definition 1.4** The following rules define the *subformulas* of a formula.
>
> 1. Any formula is a subformula of itself.
> 2. Any subformula of $F$ is also a subformula of $\neg F$.
> 3. Any subformula of $F$ or $G$ is also a subformula of $F\enspace\wedge\enspace G$.

Then Hedman gives an example:

> **Example 1.5** Let $A$ and $B$ be atomic and let $F$ be the formula $\neg(\neg A \wedge \neg B)$.
> The formula $A\wedge \neg B$ occurs as a substring of $F$, but it is not a subformula of $F$. There is no way to build the formula $F$ from the formula $A\wedge \neg B$. The subformulas of $F$ are $A$, $B$, $\neg A$, $\neg B$, $(\neg A \wedge \neg B)$ and $\neg(\neg A \wedge \neg B)$.

My question is: how can I show that $A\wedge\neg B$ is not a subformula of $\neg(\neg A \wedge \neg B)$ using only Definiton 1.4?

Comment: The definition is a recursive definition. The relation “$G$ is a subformula of $F$” is the least relation satisfying the three relevant properties. This fact allows you to explicitly construct the set of all subformulas of $F$ recursively.

Comment: @MarkSaving Can you offer a hint as to how to start the proof?

Comment: Prove an explicit recursive definition of the set of subformulas as follows. Given a formula $F$, let $Sub(F)$ be the set of subformulas of $F$. Define $Sub’(A) = \{A\}$ where $A$ is atomic; $Sub’(\neg F) = \{\neg F\} \cup Sub(F)$; and $Sub’(F \land G) = \{F \land G\} \cup Sub(F) \cup Sub(G)$. Consider the relation $R = \{(F, G) \mid F \in Sub’(G)\}$. Prove that $R$ is the relation “$F$ is a subformula of $G$”. Conclude $Sub’ = Sub$, and use this to formulate an explicit recursive definition of $Sub$. Use this definition to compute the subformulas of $\neg (\neg A \land \neg B)$.

Comment: The definition you have been given is a little loose and informal. It purports to define the subformulas of a formula but actually gives a loose definition of the property of being a subformula. It should be tightened either by adding a clause "4. No formula is a subformula of $G$ other than by virtue of rules 1, and 2, 3" or by giving an explicit set of equations for $\mathrm{Subformulas}(F)$ (along the lines of @MarkSaving's comment.

Comment: @Gary This is why you must first prove that $R = \{(F, G) \mid F$ is a subformula of $G\}$. It is easy to prove the $\subseteq$ direction; the $\supseteq$ relation requires you to show that $R$ satisfies 1, 2, and 3. Once you’ve shown this, $Sub = Sub’$ is immediate.

Comment: @MarkSaving Are you beginning with the assumption that the subformulas described in 1, 2, and 3 are the only subformulas that exist?

Comment: @Gary As I stated in my first comment, the relation “$F$ is a subformula of $G$” is defined to be the *least* relation satisfying 1, 2, and 3. Formally, this means that for any relation $R$ which satisfies 1, 2, and 3, $\{(F, G) \mid F$ is a subformula of $G\} \subseteq R$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us make the precious comments by Mark Saving and Rob Arthan into a sketch of the proof.

First, several preliminary remarks:

Every finite set of alphabet $\Sigma$ can be encoded by the natural numbers. Then, we can define a recursive language $\mathcal{L}$ over $\Sigma^{*}$, the set of strings over the alphabet $\Sigma$, such that $\mathcal{L}\subseteq\Sigma^{∗}$ and, encoded by the natural numbers, is a recursive set. We can form the alphabet $\Sigma$ and the language $\mathcal{L}$ for propositional calculus in the obvious way.

Equipped as such, we can make use of the characteristic function for any set $S$

$$
\chi_{S}(x) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{l l}
        1 & \mbox{if }x\in S\\
        0 & \mbox{if }x\notin S\ 
    \end{array}
\right.
$$

and the proposition that a finite union of recursive sets is a recursive set (see [the theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Union_of_Primitive_Recursive_Sets)).

We shall consider the following cases which can be modified and generalised as needed:

(1) If $\phi$ is an atomic formula, then $Sub'(\phi)=\{\phi\}$,

(2) If $\phi\equiv\neg\alpha$, then $Sub'(\phi)=\{\neg\alpha\}\cup Sub(\alpha)$

(3) If $\phi\equiv\alpha\wedge\beta$, then $Sub′(\phi)=\{\alpha\wedge\beta\}\cup Sub(\alpha)\cup Sub(\beta)$

We denote the set of subformulas of a formula $\phi$ given in the definition 1.4 by $Sub(\phi)$ and define the subformula relation $R=\{(\psi, \phi)\mid\psi\in Sub′(\phi)\}$. We take up the case (3) as an example:

$(\psi, \phi)\in R$ and $\psi$ is of the form $\alpha\wedge\beta$. Then, $Sub(\alpha)$ and $Sub(\beta)$ are also in the set.

$\psi\in Sub(\alpha)$ and $\psi\in Sub(\beta)$ are in one of the forms ruled in by the definition 1.4. Since those forms occur also in the definition of $Sub$', we iterate the foregoing steps, so until we reach the stage of atomic formulas.

Therefore (we could be more precise and use the ordered pairs), $Sub(\phi)\subseteq Sub'(\phi)$.

If $\psi\in Sub(\phi)$, then $Sub'(\phi)\subseteq Sub(\phi)$ since each formula is a subformula of itself.

Consequently, $Sub(\phi) = Sub'(\phi)$.

The definition 1.4 states what counts as a subformula, the formation of the set $R$ states a recursive procedure to build the set of subformulas of a formula $\phi$.

It can be thus seen that $A\wedge\neg B$ is not in the set of subformulas of $\neg(\neg A \wedge \neg B)$.